# Problematic matrix calculation

Tags: matrix, simplifying-expressions, complex

I have defined matrix as such

```
u1 = {0, I, 0, 1};
u2 = {I, 0, 1, 0};
λ1 = Sqrt[m/2] (u1 + (I*u2));
```

Now I define the matrix multiplication with $ 4\times 4 $ matrix with algebraic elements as:

```
λ1p =Sqrt[(e + m)/(2 m)] {{1 + p3/(e + m), (p1 - (I *p2))/(e + m), 0, 
  0}, {(p1 + (I* p2))/(e + m), 1 - p3/(e + m), 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
  1 - p3/(e + m), -((p1 - (I* p2))/(e + m))}, {0, 
  0, -((p1 + (I* p2))/(e + m)), 1 + p3/(e + m)}}.λ1;
```

Now again we do this:

```
k1 = (1/m)*((γ0*p0) - (γ1*p1) - (γ2*
    p2) - (γ3*p3)).λ1p;
```

Where Gamma's are any 4x4 matrix,
Now applying the conjugate:

```
l1 = k1 /. I -> -I;

bλ1p = l1.γ0;

bλ1p.λ1p,
```

This doesn't give us the desired answer.

I have used `ComplexExpand`, `Simplify` and `Fullsimplify`. I don't know where I am making the mistake. Also, where should I use `Assuming` to indicate `p0, p1, p2, p3, e, m are reals.

#### Edit

I used

```
l1 = k1 /. c_Complex :> Conjugate[c];
```

to conjugate the whole matrix, it worked. But still the final answer eludes me.

As Mathematica doesn't differentiate btw row and column matrix, I did this, where Gamma is some 4x4 matrix.

```
bλ1p = l1.γ0;
```

Then

```
bλ1p.λ1p // Simplify;
```

doesn't give the desired answer

Comment: I don't understand. lambda1 and k1 are not matrices as you have defined them, they are 4-vectors.

Comment: Please use $\texttt{Conjugate[ ]}$ to get the conjugate.

Comment: $\texttt{(1 + I) /. I -> -I}$ returns $1+i$, but $\texttt{5 /. 5 -> 3}$ returns $3$.  Anybody know why?

Comment: MMA always replaces on the "FullForm", what is not always what you see. Therefore look at (1+I) //FullForm and you will see that complex numbers are written as Complex[1,b]. With this: (1 + I) /. Complex[1, 1] -> Complex[1, -1]  gives what you want.

Comment: Well $\texttt{1 + 3 I /. Complex[1, 1] -> Complex[1, -1]}$ returns $1+3i$.

Comment: I think we agree that to find a conjugate, $\texttt{Cojugate[ ]}$ works and we have not found a general way to manufacture it with $\texttt{/.}$  I appreciate the note about $\texttt{FullForm[]}$.  That's interesting to know.

Comment: In the begining I used, $Assumptions = 
 p0 \[Element] Reals && p1 \[Element] Reals && p2 \[Element] Reals && 
  p3 \[Element] Reals && e \[Element] Reals && m \[Element] Reals 
then,  I did l1 = Conjugate[k1], but it was not evaluating the expression

Comment: @mjw Complex numbers are atomic. You can't do replacements on their real or imaginary parts. For the same reason, `Part[1 + I, 1]` doesn't work either. The proper way to do replace all complex numbers with their conjugate is  `1 + I /. c_Complex :> Conjugate[c]`.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, Yes, that makes sense.  Thank you!  What is the difference between this and simply using `Conjugate[1+I]`?

Comment: @mjw The replacement rule will work anywhere in an expression. For example `f[1 + I] /. c_Complex :> Conjugate[c]`

Comment: Hi @SjoerdSmit, Okay, great!  Got it!  Thank you very much!